# How can I power a GTX 650?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I bought a nVidia GTX 650 but my PSU doesn't have a 6 pin connector. I have an old Inter-Tech Booster 520W as PSU. For now, I can not afford a new one. How can I make a 6 pin connector ?

My idea was to buy a SATA to 4 pin Molex and a 2xMolex to 6 pin, because one Molex is used by my HDD. So I would connect the Sata to 4 pin to one of my Sata connectors and after, the 2xMolex to 6 pin.

Can this build generate enough power for the video card ? Or is it safe for now ?

Comment: Could you name your specific model of the PSU or add some information about the available connectors? Depending on that information it could or could not work.

Comment: "buy a SATA to 4 pin Molex and a 2xMolex to 6 pin, "  sounds like a good way to add a bunch of resistance, and if the adapters are crappy enough, possibly causing a fire.

Comment: Does your PSU really come with only two “big” Molex connectors? That’s *very* hard to believe.

Comment: Holy sh*t, [this PSU](http://www.pcgarage.ro/surse/inter-tech/booster-520w/) is insane. I’m not sure you could use the 520 W even if you wanted to due to lack of appropriate connectors. It’s ~$23.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your PSU. Your PSU is not compatible to your spec. Find a PSU that got ideal watt range from 750-650. Also purchase new PSU with the 6+2pin connector, 20+4 pin power motherboard, 6+2pin GPU and SATA cable. If need molex, try purchase silverstone PSU or coolermaster V series or corsair VS series.

Comment: While it would be indeed better to have a PSU that just offers a 6-pin connector how did you arrive at the 650-750 watt figure without knowing anything about his system, with the exception that it's working with a 520 watt PSU so far?

Answer (score 0):

It should be save with the GTX650. All in all your GPU don't need much power..

If your graphic card is then undersupplied it would show that by displaying it.

Anyway, your setup won't take any damage.